# Determining the contents of a number input

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an input of type number, how can I find out what the user typed if they didn't type a number?

```html
<input type="number" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
```

The above shows an empty string if I type "a" in the input. How can I get the actual contents of the input?

Comment: in type `number` user can only type only number not other character or etc

Comment: @MohammadMalek, I can type "a" and the "a" appears in the input, regardless of whether the input is of type "text" or "number".

Comment: no this is not appear

Comment: maybe you were testing on pre ie11?

Comment: Can you add your test platform to the question please.

Comment: This happens on both the latest Safari and Firefox. Either can be used for testing.

Answer (score 2):

This is the example of `type:number` did not type a any text or charterer
 only allowed number you can check this

```html
<input type="number" oninput="console.log(this.valueAsNumber)">
```

Comment: This depends on the browser. If I run the code snippet in Safari for example, I can type "a" and the "a" appears in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below events:

```
onkeyup = "console.log(event.key)"
onkeypress = "console.log(event.key)"
onkeydown = "console.log(event.key)"
```

But these will trigger as soon as they enter a key value.

In your use case, user will never be able to actually enter anything other than numbers into the input element as it is set as type="number". You can try using type="text", to differentiate values between numbers and other characters.

Comment: Whether or not the invalid text appears in the input depends on the browser. Chrome does not show it. Safari does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way since it's meant to accept numbers only.
However you could at least retrieve if the user didn't enter a number by switching to the **oninput** event and evaluating **valueAsNumber** though.

So

```
<input type="number" oninput="console.log(this.valueAsNumber)">
```

will return **NAN** if it ain't a number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a text input from a input type number so,you can do it like this

in html

```
<input type="text" onchange="detectNumber(this.value)" id = 'number_input'">
```

in js

```
let numberInput = document.querySelector('#number_input');
function detectNumber(value){
  if(isNaN(parseInt(value))){
     console.log('Text input!!')
     numberInput.value = value.split('').pop().join('');
  }

}
```